# How to save structure in shared memory C - Windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, shared-memory

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct configuration {
    char *server_type;
    char *server_ip;
    unsigned int server_port;
} configuration;
```

Now since i have more processes i need this structure to be shared between all of them ( after it's initialized by the Main process).
So i have this named shared memory:

```
TCHAR szMsg[]=TEXT("JUST A TEST");
LPCTSTR pBuf;
HANDLE hMapFile;
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, BUF_SIZE, "Global\\Config");

if (hMapFile == NULL){
    perror("Errore nel creare memory object");
    exit(1);
}

pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
if (pBuf == NULL){
    perror("Errore nel mappare la view del file");
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    exit(1);
}

CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
```

Now how can i pass the pointer of the structure insted of szMsg and from another process read it from shared memory ?

Thanks

Comment: You have to simply open the mapping in the other executable. This sample from MS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-shared-memory-in-a-dynamic-link-library give an example of what you're trying to implement using a DLL for the memory sharing.

Comment: Unless your pointers point into shared memory, they are meaningless in the target process. And even then it's *way* easier to just store values in an appropriate format (like a size-refixed string).

Comment: Yes, it works with fixed size char array, like char string[xx] but why it doesn't work with a pointer in the struct and then a malloc ? should not be the same thing? i'm new in C don't hang me.

Comment: Why dont use fixed sized char arrays in struct???

Comment: @use: What size? If you don't have an answer for that, you'll understand why not a fixed-size array.

Comment: @use: *"Server ip never be greater than 15"* - There's IPv6. And while this question uses server IP and type, the generalized problem uses data that has no fixed upper bound in general.

Comment: @IInspectable: Again and again: OP is author of configuration struct, so HE may define fixed size members. Dont understand?

Comment: @user2120666 Yeah that's my case, i can ( and i did ) use fixed size array, but my question was about the scenario in which the size of something is not fixed... like a text read from a file, the file may be larger or smaller. I thought that malloc should do the trick, but it doesn't... So is this meaning that we can't have a structure with variable size attributes in sharedmem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable with the data type "configuration* structPoint", then instead of 'TCHAR szMsg' pass structPoint.

Comment: That doesn't solve anything. Pointers are meaningful in the process that created them only. Passing that pointer into another process doesn't get you anywhere.